# Grafana: how to put time-filter in panel title?

Tags: grafana

I have a variant time filter (in the screenshot it's "Last 6 hours") and I want to present it in the title of the panel.
I want to present the time-filter in the title, and make it dynamic.

The only thing I found is this:

> ${__from:date:DD-MM-YYYY HH}:${__from:date:mm} To ${__to:date:DD-MM-YYYY HH}:${__to:date:mm}

It's not bad, but it's too cumbersome. I want to see "Last 6 hours" in the title.

I also tried to use $__timeFilter, but it didn't work out.

Do you have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `duration` function does not seem to work in the panel titles (v. 8.4 at the least).

Thus you can try to imply the period with a "since" sentence/statement structure:

```
`Detected events since ${__from:date:MMM-DD h.ma}`
```

You should get something like

> Detected events since Mar-09 12.53pm

Hope it helps.